# What does NASM's resb do in binary output format?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, x86-16

I saw a piece of NASM code that uses `resb`. However, this code runs in a real mode operating system, and the output format is flat binary. NASM doesn't give an error when doing this, but after dissecting the output file, I still couldn't find what actually happens.

```
bits 16
org 0x8000

start:
    mov ax, msg
    call os_input_string
    mov si, msg
    call os_print_string
    ret

section .bss
msg: resb 256
```

Here are a few possibilities that I've thought of:

- `resb` simply allocates some unused space at the end of the binary
- it doesn't really work at all, and stuff blows up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When *NASM* generates a binary `-f bin` it follows some basic rules about the sections. The [*NASM* manual](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc7.html) says this:

> 7.1.3 Multisection Support for the bin Format
>
> [snip]
>
> - The .bss section will be placed after the last progbits section, unless start=, vstart=, follows=, or vfollows= has been specified.

`progbits` is a flag that denotes a section will physically appear in the file (the default for `.text` and `.data` sections).  `.bss` defaults to `nobits` which means the data reserved in this section doesn't physically appear in the file, but any addresses of labels in a `nobits` flagged section will resolve (by default) to the memory just past the last `progbits` (`.text` and `.data` etc) section. The *BSS* area *in a binary file* is not initialized to zero. It will be whatever happens to be in memory, so consider the area to contain garbage. If you need a binary program to initialize this area to zero, you will have to do it yourself once your program starts executing.

There are hints in your question that you are creating the second stage of a bootloader. I'm going to provide an example of code that will initialize the *BSS* area with zeros. This code assumes that the second stage was loaded at 0x0000:0x8000 :

```
bits 16
org 0x8000

section .text
start:
    ; Initialize the entire BSS area to zero
    ; Assume we are the second stage of a bootloader at 0x0000:0x8000
    mov cx, _bss_end-_bss_start    ; Length of region in CX
    xor ax, ax                     ; AX=0 (also used for rep stos)
    mov es, ax
    mov ds, ax                     ; DS=ES=0x0000
    mov di, _bss_start             ; Offset of BSS region 
    rep stosb                      ; Set CX bytes of data at ES:[DI] to AL(0)

    mov ax, msg
    mov si, msg2

    ; Put second stage in halt state indefinitely.
    cli
.endloop:
    hlt
    jmp .endloop

section .bss
_bss_start:      ; Label for start of BSS
msg: resb 256
msg2: resb 10
_bss_end:        ; Label at end of BSS
```

Although the memory for *BSS* is not part of the binary file on disk, the labels for data in this area resolve to real offsets. You can tag the beginning and end of the *BSS* area, and in this case I use `_bss_start` and `_bss_end`. These labels are used to determine the extent of the *BSS* area so that it can be initialized to zero when our code begins to execute.

Comment: FYI: NASM creates a symbol `section.bss.start`, so you don't need to specify it manually. Not sure about the end though, so it might be cleaner to define the symbols manually anyway.

Comment: @AnonymousShadow You are quite correct, it does but for purposes of clarity I specified the start label so you can see how the mechanism works. This technique can also be used for assemblers that may not create  hidden labels as NASM does. I don't believe there is an end label generated by NASM, just the start.

Answer (score 3):

This is all written in the manual of course. [`resb` reserves uninitialized storage in the `.bss` section](http://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.11.08/html/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.2.2). Furthermore, `bin` files have [limited section support](http://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.11.08/html/nasmdoc7.html#section-7.1.3), in particular:

> Sections may be designated progbits or nobits. Default is progbits (except
>   .bss, which defaults to nobits, of course). 
>   The .bss section will be placed after the last progbits section,
>   unless start=, vstart=, follows=, or vfollows= has been specified.

As such, "*resb simply allocates some unused space at the end of the binary*" is basically what happens. Not sure why you couldn't see this from dissecting the output file.

Answer (score 2):

Since the .bss section never has any initialized data (set as `nobits`), it doesn't need to be written into the file. When using flat binary format NASM will just calculate a suitable pointer for the variable and that's it.

By disassembling the code you can easily see what happens. I compiled this code:

```
bits 16
org 0x8000

start:
    mov ax, msg
    ret

section .bss
msg: resb 256
```

When running the resulting binary through ndisasm:

```
00000000  B80480            mov ax,0x8004
00000003  C3                ret
```

So you can clearly see that NASM had written four bytes of code and determined that the .bss section can be put right after that, starting at position 0x8004. So nothing is allocated in the binary, only the pointers are calculated based on the desired allocations in .bss.